# How to install blackberry webworks 2.0 phonegap app to remote device...?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, installation, blackberry-webworks

This is my first app for blackberry webworks.

As my application ready for android with phonegap. I just download blackberry webworks 2.0 which have graphical UI for app development.
[image]

I test it on blackberry simulator with selecting **DEBUG MODE** and **SIMULATOR** radio button selected **BUILD & INSTALL**.

Like when we create android app, with **EXPORT** we can generate .apk and can install same on any android device. I want to send this app to client for testing on device which they have(blackberry z10).

Can anyone guide me what is the process or/and requirement for all.

I'm using mac as os.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a .bar (say "yourapp.bar") file of your project. Steps for same is given here - http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/deploy_to_a_device.html#kba1371658832687

And thereafter you will need to repackage "yourapp.bar" to "yourapp.apk" using Android repackaging tool. https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/mastertopic_1849583_11.html

Let me know, if I am misunderstanding your requirement.

Comment: Hello Kanak, Thanks for your reply. I already go through all this documents, but they all guide you for, when you have physical device to test. But as I mention, I want to send a installation file to my client, which they can install.

Comment: you can create a build through your SDK, without physical device. Which SDK are you using?

Comment: blackberry webworks 2.0, which graphical UI i added in my question.

Comment: I guess "build" button will generate you .bar at some location on your system.

Comment: Thanks you lady, yes build generate me .bar file that's true with location I know. But I'm not sure that what is the proper option to select and generate that for run that without any issue in client device. If any guidance plz jainmanishfriend@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve that.

**OPTION 1**: Anyone you send the app to can install it
You sign the application and send the signed bar file that they can sideload.
Select "Release mode" and "Device" checkboxes in the WebWorks UI and press "Build". A file will be created in

```
your_project_dir/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/
```

and that's the signed BAR file that you can send for anyone to use.

**OPTION 2**: Only selected people can run it
You need to create a debug token with your client's PIN, you build the application selecting the "Debug" and "Device" checkboxes, press "Build" and send both the debugtoken.bar and application.bar to your client.